# rightView property error in iOS7 for UITextField

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I am setting an imageView as the rightView of a textfield. This is my code:

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:controlFrame];
    [textField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
    [textField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    CGRect imageViewFrame = CGRectMake(controlFrame.origin.x + controlFrame.size.width - 20,controlFrame.origin.y, 15.0,controlFrame.size.height-10);
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"];;
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    [imageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [imageView setFrame:imageViewFrame];
    [textField setRightViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
    textField.rightView = imageView;
```

Its working perfect on iOS 6.1 devices[image]

But in iOS 7 devices  [image]

Any Solution for this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Was just working on this myself and used this solution:

```
- (CGRect) rightViewRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {

CGRect textRect = [super rightViewRectForBounds:bounds];
textRect.origin.x -= 10;
return textRect;
}
```

This will move the image over from the right by 10 instead of having the image squeezed up against the edge in iOS 7.

Additionally, this was in a subclass of UITextField, which can be created by:

Create a new file that's a subclass of UITextField instead of the default NSObject
Add a new method named - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder to set the image

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder {
self = [super initWithCoder:coder];

if (self) {

    self.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [self setRightViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeUnlessEditing];

    self.leftView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage     imageNamed:@"textfield_edit_icon.png"]];
}

return self;
}
```

You may have to import #import

Add the rightViewRectForBounds method above

In Interface Builder, click on the TextField you would like to subclass and change the class attribute to the name of this new subclass

Answer (score 0):

There's another faster option, no need to subclass your uitextfield. There's an example

```
 UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 6)];
[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"grey_filter.png"]];

UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 6)];
[paddingView addSubview:imageView];
```

Just create a View bigger than your image with your padding. Add your UIImageView and then put it as left/right view in your textfield.